# Select all data attribute elements generically

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to select all the elements that have a `data` attribute that starts with `data-id-`, just like I would do with a class that starts with page

```js
console.log(
 document.querySelectorAll("[class*=card]")
)
```

```html
<div class="card-1">
<div class="card-2">
```

I want to do this but for data attributes

Comment: For what purpose? I would just add a class to all those with data-*, so you can select them via that specific class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

best approach will be to specify `data-id="{ID}"` and then you can do it like this

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-id]");

console.log(elements)
```

```html
<div data-id="1"></div>
<div data-id="2"></div>
```

Selecting `data-id-1`, `data-id-2` and so on will be a little trickier and much, MUCH, ***MUCH*** more resource consuming on larger sites because you will have to iterate every single element and then iterate all its attrs to find those that you are interested in.

```js
const filter = Array.prototype.filter;
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("*");

const filtered = filter.call(elements, element => {
    let ret = false;
    Array.from(element.attributes).forEach(key => {
        ret = !!key.localName.match(/data-id-\d+/gm);
    })
    return ret;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<div data-id-1></div>
<div data-id-2></div>
```

If you are sure that there will only be elements with attr `data-id-1` and `data-id-2` you can simplify it to:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-id-1], [data-id-2]");

console.log(elements)
```

```html
<div data-id-1></div>
<div data-id-2></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can select all elements, and then check if each element has a `dataset`.

```js
function getAllElementsWithData() {
  let allNodes = document.querySelectorAll('*');
  let allElements = Array.from(allNodes);

  let dataElements = allElements.filter((element) => {
    let hasDataset = Object.keys(element.dataset).length;
    return hasDataset;
  });

  return dataElements;
}

// ------- 

let dataElements = getAllElementsWithData();

console.log('Number of elements with data attribute:', dataElements.length)

for (const element of dataElements) {
  console.log(element.dataset);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-1">
<div class="card-2">
<div data-id="1"></div>
<div data-greeting="hello"></div>
<div data-user="world"></div>
```

[EDIT] If you want to select based on "data-id-*".

I made the method more dynamic, so you can add a parameter that takes what the data attribute should start with, or you can skip the parameter and just get all elements that has a data attribute.

```js
function getAllElementsWithData(startsWith) {
  let allNodes = document.querySelectorAll('*');
  let allElements = Array.from(allNodes);

  let dataElements = allElements.filter((element) => {

    for (const dataIdKey in element.dataset) {
      if (!startsWith || dataIdKey.startsWith(startsWith)) {
        return true
      }
    }

    return false;
  });

  return dataElements;
}

// ------- 

let dataElements = getAllElementsWithData('id');

console.log('Number of data elements:', dataElements.length)

for (const element of dataElements) {
  console.log(element.dataset);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-1">
<div class="card-2">
<div data-id-something="1"></div>
<div data-id-something-else="2"></div>
<div data-greeting="hello"></div>
<div data-user="world"></div>
```

Comment: No more brute forcing than your answer. How do you think querySelectorAll works? It still needs to loop through all elements, even if the selector is more specific.

Comment: Fair enough. I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to select all elements with a data-* attribute using querySelectorAll, but if you know the explicit name of the data attribute, like "data-id", you can select it like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-id]");
```

---

```
<div data-id="1"></div>
<div data-id="2"></div>
<div data-id="3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no "built-in" way you can use. However, it's not too hard to implement a function that does it:

```js
function queryByDataAttrs(prefix, postfixes) {
  return postfixes.reduce(
    (acc, postfix) => { 
      // we use a try-catch here, because it might be we generate invalid selectors
      try {
        let nodes = document.querySelectorAll(`[${prefix}-${postfix}]`); // find the elements
        return nodes.length ? acc.concat(Array.from(nodes)) : acc; // got some? the concatenate them to the result. otherwise ignore
      } catch (exc) {
        return acc; // ignore exceptions and just return the results so far
      }
    },
    []
  );
}

console.log(queryByDataAttrs('data-id', ['foo', 'bar']));
```

```html
<div class="card-1" data-id-foo="card-1">
<div class="card-2" data-id-bar="card-2">
```